# Azure logic app - How can I share integration account across multiple resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to deploy my logic app to multiple environments using CI/CD pipeline. I am getting an error -The client 'guid' with object id ''guid' ' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write' on scope 'Test Resource group'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action' on the linked scope(s) 'Development Resource group integration account' or the linked scope(s) are invalid.

Creating another integration account for test resource group doesnt come under free tier. Is there a way to share integration account across multiple resource groups

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the permissions issue is but you might need to give more information around this.

But try the below first in your pipeline. Works for us with 3 different resource groups and two integration accounts

```
"parameters": {
"IntegrationAccountName": {
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 1,
    "defaultValue": "inter-account-name"
},
"Environment": {
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 1,
    "defaultValue": "dev"
}
```

},

```
"variables": {
"resourceGroupName": "[if(equals(parameters('Environment'), 'prd'),'rg-resources-production','rg-resources-staging')]",
"LogicAppIntegrationAccount": "[concat('/subscriptions/3fxxx4de-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-88ccxxxfbab4/resourceGroups/',variables('resourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/',parameters('IntegrationAccount'))]",
```

},

In the above sample, we had two different integration accounts one for testing and one for production. This is why I have set the integration account name as a parameter as it changes between environments.

I have created a variable "resourceGroupName" this is important because this url is setting up a direct link to the integration account which is stored in a known resource group. In this sample I have included an if statement using the value set at the "environment" parameter. This helps select which resource group is going to be used.

I then create another variable which stores the new URL. Replace the subscription guid with your own: 3fxxx4de-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-88ccxxxfbab4.

Once that is created you need to change the ARM template to use the variable you just created. To set it,place in the properties object.

```
"properties": {
"state": "Enabled",
"integrationAccount": {
    "id": "[variables('LogicAppIntegrationAccount')]"
},
```

So for you pipeline it should just be a normal arm template but with these two parameters above being set.

Let me know if you have more questions around this.